# Mode of duration gives wrong value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Mode returned the wrong value so i checked the data. Apparently 5:00:00 x 4 is false with countunique(), i formatted it into text, and again the same result.

5:00:00 occurred 4times but 6:00:00 (0.25) occurred only 3 but that value was returned.

What do I do, how do I fix this? Thanks!

[image: problem]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is likely due to the way numbers are implemented

I am not sure, but it seems that Sheets use floating-point numbers, which will get into rounding errors, especially for recurring numbers like `.3333333333...`. This will lead to rounding errors and for things that should be identical, no longer being so.

So `(1 / 3) != (1 / 3)` sometimes, but not always!

#### Workaround

To work around this, I suggest that you use `ROUND` within an `ARRAYFORMULA` to round the number to a reasonable number of decimal places, before applying any kind of comparison operator.

```
=COUNTUNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(ROUND(L5:L8)))=1
```

#### Reference

- [`ROUND`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093440)
- [`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)